# WebKitCSSMatrix rotate method on iOS (safari, chrome, and other browsers) generates matrix different than the method in other OS

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, matrix, webkit

Using the constructor WebKitCSSMatrix I use 'rotate' method to generate a matrix (string) which I apply on a DOM element.

```js
var square = document.querySelector('.square');

var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix().rotate(15);

square.style.webkitTransform = matrix;
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}
.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="square"><span>test</span>
    <div></div>
```

In the above example the rectangle should not be visible.

Now most major devices work well. However, ipad (tested on two different devices) generates matrix with a and d value equals to 0 - transform:  matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty).

Above example generates:

Safari or Chrome on iOS (8.3) ipadMini matrix generated:
matrix(0, 0.258819, 0, 0.965926, 0, 0);

Chrome on Mac Yosemite, Win8.1, Android (or any other browser on those devices):
matrix(0.965926, 0.258819, -0.258819, 0.965926, 0, 0);

Is that an already reported bug relating to ipad devices or I miss some sort of 'rotate' method intention there?

Comment: Now I can see that the issue is very limited to only some devices. I was able to recreate it on 2 different devices (ipadMini iOS 8.3, ipad 3 retina iOS 8.3). However, it worked on ipad Air iOS 8.3 :/ - I'm confused at this point...

Comment: This is really strange. I tried to restart, restore the iOS, uninstall all unnecessary applications from ipadMini, clearing browsers' memory but to no avail. What's more, I installed different browser (Opera Mini, Dolphin, Mercury) to see if it will change but the issue still exists in those browsers as well. So that's tested on Chrome, Safari, Dolphin, Mercury now. From my knowledge they all share [Webkit engine code base](https://www.webkit.org/building/build.html) and there were some changes to WebkitCSSMatrix recently. However, I'm not a Webkit dev to be able to sort it out :/

Comment: additional js fiddle [test](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianS1987/c5c0r4y6/18/)